# C++ rule of three for encupsalator objects

Tags: c++, object, encapsulation

Here is my scenario:

```
class Database {

    public:
        Database();
        ~Database();

        void close();
                ...

    private:

        sqlite3 *database; //SQLITE3 OBJECT
        bool isOpenDb;
        ...

};

Database::Database() {

    database = 0;
    filename = "";
    isOpenDb = false;
}

Database::~Database() {
    close();
}

void Database::close() {
    sqlite3_close(database); 
    isOpenDb = false;
}
```

When **Database** object is destroyed, I want that the **sqlite3** object is closed. In this form, it seems that it can be an unsafe approach since if I copy the object and I destroy it, then the copied object is in an invalid state.

In your opinion, what is the best way to proceed? I was thinking about singleton class but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Sounds like `Database` should be non-copyable (yet moveable).

Comment: @sftrabbit thanks! can you argue your arguments?

Comment: You could also use a smart pointer for the `sqlite3` object.

Comment: @Andrey thank you too! again, can you argue your arguments?

Comment: For sftrabbit and Andrey. Sorry for my english, I mean "develop your arguments and please give me some more informations"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your class noncopyable. In C++11:

```
class Database {
public:
  Database(const Database&) = delete;
  Database& operator=(const Database&) = delete;
};
```

In C++03:

```
class Database {
private: // inaccessible 
  Database(const Database&);
  Database& operator=(const Database&);
};
```

Or with Boost:

```
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
class Database : private boost::noncopyable {
};
```

In C++11 I would also make the object `Movable` by giving it a MoveConstructor and Move assignment operators. There you would assign the handle (or whatever your db gives you) to the new object and use some flag in the old object to indicate that nothing needs to be closed.

Don't forget to implement `swap` as well!

```
class Database {
  // This might look odd, but is the standard way to do it without a namespace.
  // If you have a namespace surrounding Database, put it there.
  friend void swap(Database& a, Database& b) { /* code to swap a and b */ }
};
```

Also: setting some value to false in your destructor has no effect. Nothing should ever be able to see the change.

Or using a `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
struct CloseDatabase {
  void operator()(sqlite* x) { sqlite3_close(x); }
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<sqlite3, CloseDatabase> Database;
```

Comment: As @Andrey suggested in the question comments, you could also manage the `database` member with a `std::unique_ptr` - I think this would implicitly make `Database` non-copyable but moveable.

Comment: @sftrabbit Very good point. I assumed that an object is used for encapsulation because some high-level options regarding database access should go there as well.

Comment: @pmr it looks great! can you better explain what you mean in the final part (from "Don't forget to implement swap as well!)?

Comment: @the_candyman On pre C++11 compilers swap can be abused as a poor mans move. That can come in handy and algorithms sometimes require it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a shared pointer [0], considering your application is single-threaded.

The copy-constructor will then be trivial, and the object will be destroyed when the last instantiation of your class is destroyed.

```
private:
  std::shared_ptr<sqlite3> database;
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out by pmr, a custom deleter is needed in this case to close the database. For example a simple lambda :

```
database = std::shared_ptr<sqlite3>(new database,
                                    [](sqlite3 *db)
                                    { db->close; delete db; });
```

Or you can use a functor as a deleter.

Singleton will make your class non-copyable, if that's what you want, you can do this.

Or just disable copy constructor and copy operator (and move equivalents). C++11 provides the keyword delete to do this.

```
Database(const Database &) = delete;
Database & operator =(const Database &) = delete;
Database(Database &&) = delete;
Database & operator =(Database &&) = delete;
```

[0] http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: You would still need a custom deleter.

Comment: @pmr I asume the deleter of the sqlite3 class closes the database itself.

Comment: Which isn't the case if you look at OPs example code. A special function has to be called. I think that part of your answer is lacking crucial information to be of use.

Comment: @pmr You're right, I added and example to asign the pointer with a deleter :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's a good reason to do otherwise, disable the copy constructor and assignment operator and do not permit copies.  If there's a good reason to permit copies, then exploring what that reason is will help you understand what semantics you actually want when there is a copy and that should lead to a design.